# how to fix global gulp not working on mac

Tags: gulp

I am having problem with installing npm global package

for example

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

but when i want to run "gulp" it won't run

```
Local gulp not found in ~
Try running: npm install gulp
```

running which gulp => /usr/local/bin/gulp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can find [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#getting-started) in the guide,
you have to install gulp also in your project dependencies

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

if you try gulp outside a project with gulp instlled as depedency you'll recevie that error

hope this helps