# Error after installing gulp globally

Tags: javascript, gulp

I did `$ npm install gulp -g` and I am getting this error

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/gulp: No such file or directory

node version:
`v5.0.0`

I am using OSX.

what could be happening?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3028

Comment: @RubenYeghikyan it doesn't say anything to me

Comment: did you tried to clear cache? `npm cache clean` or maybe npm update will be helpful

Comment: `sudo npm install npm -g`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284634/upgrade-nodejs-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os

Comment: If I run gulp in the terminal I get this: -bash: gulp: command not found
@RubenYeghikyan

Comment: oh. you just need to add path variable to `$PATH`

Comment: also check out this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224831/no-command-gulp-found-after-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said in the [gulp guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966312/how-to-fix-global-gulp-not-working-on-mac/36971572#36971572) you have to install cli and than you need to have gulp in your project dependencies in order to run.

So first:

```
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

And than inside your project

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

I replied to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966312/how-to-fix-global-gulp-not-working-on-mac/36971572#36971572)

hope this helps